# jQuery won't check checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I need help with auto checking checkboxes in treeview.

I have a treeview, when I click checkbox, all child items in list will have their checkboxes automatically checked. The problem is it won't work.

```
treeview.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    $j(this).click(function () {
        if ($j(this).is(':checked')) {
            $j(this).siblings('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            $j(this).siblings('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

So the code says it all, I find all checkboxes, and on each I bind click event. When the item is clicked, it checks if it is checked, then find all checkboxes and set their attribute to checked, else find all checkboxes and remove their checked attribute. My selectors work okay, so that isn't the problem.

When I click on a checkboxes, all checkboxes get checked, and when I uncheck, it's still working. But on another try, it doesn't work anymore! That's very weird! And the weirdest thing is that when I inspect code, I can see on checkbox that it has `checked="checked"` but browser won't render the checked state (actually this is the main problem).

Comment: Try `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use:

```
$el.prop('checked', true) // to check the box
$el.prop('checked', false) // to uncheck the box
```

Instead of:

```
$el.attr('checked', 'checked') // to check the box
$el.removeAttr('checked') // to uncheck the box
```

This is because you need to change the checked state of the box, not the checked attribute. The checked attribute is just for the initial state of the checkbox.